# Looping Over An Object And Populating A Select Element With Options and Values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to populate that '#shuttle-dst' (for shuttle destination) select element in the code below with options based on the values of a given configuration object. This code does what I want it to which is first clear the select element of the options that previously existed, it then loops through the assigned properties of the configs object, and prints to the console just the value of the name properties in this example there were five in this particular configuration:

```
Admin User
MPR User
SAMHSA User
States User
All States User
```

But this code does not populate the select element with all five of the assigned values, just the last one--'All States User'.  Why?

```
function loadConfigurations(configs){
   $('#shuttle-dst').empty();
   for(var i=0; i < configs.assigned.length; i++){
    var item = configs.assigned[i];
    console.log(item.name);

        $.each(item, function(){
          $('#shuttle-dst').html('<option value="' + item.value + '">' + item.name + '</option>');
        });
   }
}
```

Comment: Why are you calling $.each() on item?

Comment: Because I want to iterate over each one of the items and add them to the select element ('#shuttle-dst') as options.

Comment: But isn't the for loop already iterating over each item?

Comment: $.html() will set the HTML contents of `#shuttle-dst` not append to them.  You should look into appending to `#shuttle-dst`.

Comment: Yes thank you the for loop is already iterating over each item.  And I will try appending each item instead.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you don't need to call `$.each()`, since you're already inside the for loop for each item.

To address your issue, you should use `append()` on your #shuttle-dst element instead of `html()` (`append()` adds a new element to the caller element, `html()` replaces the html of the caller element).

For example:

```
function loadConfigurations(configs) {
    $('#shuttle-dst').empty();
    for (var i=0; i < configs.assigned.length; i++) {
        var item = configs.assigned[i];
        $('#shuttle-dst').append(
            '<option value="' + item.value + '">' + item.name + '</option>'
        );
    }
}
```